# Неправильно отображается перспективная плоскость

Tags: c++, графика, 3d, матрицы

Ребята привет, может кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой.Теперь суть, мы имеем плоскость, которую наклоняем от себя, со стороны наблюдателя. Получается перспективная проекция.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем я пытаюсь ее приблизить, не масштабировать, а именно приблизить и получается такой артефак

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую  матрицу перспективной проекции, вот участок кода:

```
his->p.rho = 20000;   /* параметр отвечает за перспективу*/

this->p.theta = 90 * atan(1.0) / 45.0;
this->p.phi = (0...360 ) * atan(1.0) / 45.0;


double st = sin(p.theta), ct = cos(p.theta), sp = sin(p.phi), cp = 
cos(p.phi);

float v13 = -sp * ct;
float v23 = -sp * -st;
float v33 = -cp;
int v43 = his->p.rho;

int x = plane3d_perspective[i].first;
int y = plane3d_perspective[i].second;
int z = 0;

//v43 тут как раз отвечает за дальность задней плоскости отсечения
double tempsx = v13 * x + v23 * y + z * v33 + v43;    


if (this->p.with_perspective)//если нужна перспектива,то идет преобразование
        {
            plane3d_perspective[i].first = (LONG)(p.d * (plane3d_perspective[i].first) / ((tempsx)));
            plane3d_perspective[i].second = (LONG)(p.d * (plane3d_perspective[i].second) / ((tempsx)));
        }
```

Comment: А что это у вас такая мешанина `int` `float` `doublt` `LONG`? Почему бу не использовать готовые функции для построения матрицы перспективной проекции?

Comment: и что, причем тут это,знак не теряется и переполнения нет, т.к значения убывают от 20000 до 1.float у меня в коде double, по памяти набирал

Comment: 1. Как вы используете получившуюся матрицу (её коэффициенты) при трансформации позиции точек? Приведите пример кода. 2. Что такое `plane3d_perspective`, и как он объявлен?